# Can I run Ubuntu Server on an Raspberry Pi 2 Model B?

Tags: ubuntu

I only read that you can install Ubuntu Mate and Snappy. I don't need the graphic interface, so I'd like to go with the server version and use it as a file-server in my home network.

Comment: is there a specific reason why you would want Ubuntu over Raspbian?
Just curious.

Comment: I was used to Ubuntu Server and I thought Raspbian boots you into a graphical interface. Then I found out about the Raspbian Lite img and went with that. It lets you choose if you want to use the graphic interface or not: `sudo raspi-config` .So far I'm happy with it. You can download it here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/

Comment: You don't neet to convince me, I already use Raspbian ;) was just curious as to why you would prefer an Ubuntu over Raspbian in specific.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of pre-built "Flavours". You can also mix your own. See https://ubuntu-pi-flavour-maker.org/blog/ubuntu-pi-flavours-for-wily-released/

Comment: _"These images are not supported by Canonical or the Raspberry Pi Foundation."_ How about (security) update support then? It seems like they depend on custom community updates? And what about support duration?

Comment: @le0m I am not promoting these, just answering your question. I run MATE which has community support. Most of the code is from the Ubuntu base so should be supported. If this worries you use  Raspbian Jessie Lite and configure as a server. Raspbian is a better performer on the Pi, but you would have to benchmark a server build to see if there is a significant difference.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, I'm running it myself. It works fine, some weird kernel compiling issues, but no problems at all. Feel free to ask

Comment: And which image did you use?

Comment: snappy and LTS, tried both. IMHO Snappy is not ready yet, so I've finished with the LTS + new kernel compiled from source combo

Comment: So you use the standard LTS Server Image? Which kernel did you put into LTS? How do you perform kernel updates?

Comment: Kernel from git, stable branch, I've inserted it in standart server LTS image and I'm building kernel manually by hand.

Comment: Do you have a link to the branch? How much work is it to keep the implemented kernel up to date? Is it doable or do you just plan to stay on the same kernel without frequent updates?

Comment: It's doable and even more : I'm making my own Linux distro right now =) The Git is [here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux) you can also try [this address](git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git)

Answer (score 1):

There is a community maintained version of [Ubuntu Server for ARM/Raspberry Pi](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi) on the Ubuntu Wiki - I'm using it and it works just fine.

The only downside is that there are no RPi specific options (like `raspi config`), but things like resizing partitions is easy enough manually.